# Unable to edit 'Assigned To' field in Mobile Browser

Tags: mobile

I am unable to edit 'Assigned To' field in Mobile Browser (image attached). It is not editable like Date, Title fields. And

While creating new item ->

- In people/group option only groups are there that also very few groups
- In people - Very few users are seen

Any ideas how to solve it?

I am on Android Browser using the default Mobile Browser.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit using normal browsers?

Comment: Facing no issues whatsover with normal browsers like FF, IE etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wich permissions do you have on the object.
Perhabs you do not have permissions to change the assigned to attribute.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx

Greetings

Comment: I am admin. And, the field is not editable for any users.